# What is this horizontally growing weed with blue flowers?

Tags: identification, weeds

What is this weed? It is what I mostly encountered when cleaning a bed of flowers after the winter here in Central Europe. The weed has blue flowers (approx. 0.5 cm in diameter) and grows mainly horizontally and close to the ground. It is also simple to tear out, a bit like [chickweed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellaria_media) in this way.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a type of Veronica, I'd estimate [Veronica chamaedrys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veronica_chamaedrys) based on flower colour and amount & shape of foliage.

It's considered a weed by many gardeners, but as I personally like the flowers, I tend to disagree (or agree to disagree...).

Comment: Clarification: it's not considered a weed in my entire garden, but in nevertheless try to keep it out of certain beds :)